Big query exception handling only throwing one error
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_project.proc1() BEGIN
  SELECT 1/0;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_project.proc2() BEGIN
  SELECT 2/0;
END;

BEGIN
  CALL my_project.proc1();
  CALL my_project.proc2();
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT
    @@error.message as error_msg,
    @@error.statement_text as query,
    @@error.formatted_stack_trace as stack_trace;
END;

Running the final query, I only get one exception/error message but I would like both proc1 and proc2 to throw an error in the final query. What would be the best approach to take here in bq?
For reference, the error we are getting is

Query error: division by zero: 1 / 0 at [my_project.proc1:2:3]


can you please add the errror as text as well

Added for context

ok in math you learnt that a division with 0 is not permuted at all, so you get an error rightfully, what would you expect?

A process can only raise a single error. You would need to wrap each SP call in its own error handler and the write code at the end to raise a custom error containing whatever information you want to include from the individual error handlers

Oh I'm expecting an error. I just want the error to also be thrown for the 2nd procedure.

Apologies if I didn’t explain it well enough. Your process, that starts with BEGIN will run unless it encounters an error. If it encounters an error it will run the code in the EXCEPTION and then stop. So if the first call to an SP causes an error the 2nd SP will never run and so will never error. If you want both SPs to run the you would need to wrap each one in its own exception handler that didn’t stop the process and then have code at the end that determines if either/both SPs errored and takes whatever action you want. If that action is to raise an error then it can only ever be one error

Gotcha, so I have to run multiple begin statements and save it to like some table somewhere

It looks like you can have an EXCEPTION clause for each BEGIN..END block.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language
Would this allow you to handle them separately:
BEGIN
    BEGIN
      CALL my_project.proc1();
    EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
      SELECT
        @@error.message as error_msg,
        @@error.statement_text as query,
        @@error.formatted_stack_trace as stack_trace;
    END;
    
    BEGIN
      CALL my_project.proc2();
    EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
      SELECT
        @@error.message as error_msg,
        @@error.statement_text as query,
        @@error.formatted_stack_trace as stack_trace;
    END;
END;

